# rails openshift image-path not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, openshift, assets

I have problem with image in stylesheet files. Here is description:

I am using rails 4.1.1 and sass 4.0.3 and I am deploing to OpenShift. I need to server image url in my scss files. I read lot of documentation, but I cannot find answer.

I found this:

```
2.3.2 CSS and Sass

When using the asset pipeline, paths to assets must be re-written and sass-rails provides -url and -path helpers (hyphenated in Sass, underscored in Ruby) for the following asset classes: image, font, video, audio, JavaScript and stylesheet.

image-url("rails.png") becomes url(/assets/rails.png)
image-path("rails.png") becomes "/assets/rails.png". 
The more generic form can also be used:

asset-url("rails.png") becomes url(/assets/rails.png)
asset-path("rails.png") becomes "/assets/rails.png"
```

**I have images in app/assets/images!**

So in my scss file (main.css.scss) I am using this:

```
background: url(image-path('clothes-line.jpg'));
```

In development mode everything works just fine, but in production on openshift it wont add hash at the end of image url. So the url is:

```
background-image: url("/assets/clothes-line.jpg");
```

but it should be:

```
background-image: url("/assets/clothes-line-d8c5459295983599e58ddb8f7e6aa010.jpg");
```

I dont know why. I tried precompile assets, increase asset version number, change some configs. Nothing helps.

Can you help me please.

**UPDATE:**

OK here is web, which I am dealing with:

http://origi-railsshop.rhcloud.com/

In header is black background, because image is missing. Use some tool to see css, for example Firebug.

```
background-image: url("/assets/clothes-line.jpg");
```

Try to edit and add hash:

```
background-image: url("/assets/clothes-line-d8c5459295983599e58ddb8f7e6aa010.jpg");
```

It will load the image.

**SOLVED (cannot send answer until 8 hours, so I put answer here):**

So it works now.

Sadly, I am not sure what cause that. I played with configuration and rhc tool and it started work after I fired command:

```
rhc app deploy -a <app_id> --ref <commit_id>
```

I have also uncommented line in config/enviroments/production.rb:

```
config.assets.css_compressor = :sass
```

And I also played with in same file:

```
config.assets.compile
```

But I have found good description about asset.compile here: http://blog.55minutes.com/2012/02/untangling-the-rails-asset-pipeline-part-3-configuration/

and I switched it back to false. Because in production it should be false, because otherwise it would precompile assets on the fly whenever the browser makes a request.

However I cannot reproduce my problem now so I am not sure which of these actions was the one.

Thanks for answers.

Comment: why can't you simply use background: image-url("clothes-line.jpg")?

Comment: Because after precompile there is no image with name clothes-line.jpg.  The asset pipeline automatically adds fingerprint at the end. So in my public folder is assets folder and inside are images like this clothes-line-d8c5459295983599e58ddb8f7e6aa010.jpg.

Comment: you have your image in public folder?

Comment: Yes, I have images precompiled in /public/assets/. This is URL of that image: http://origi-railsshop.rhcloud.com/assets/clothes-line-d8c5459295983599e58ddb8f7e6aa010.jpg

Comment: I had the same problem.
config.assets.compile = true solved for me!

Thank you very much.

Comment: See also https://github.com/openshift/origin-community-cartridges/issues/8#issuecomment-164117702

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You need to put your images inside **app/assets/images** folder in order to make use of rails asset pipeline.* If your image is inside app/assets/images folder then you can use rails [`asset_path or image-url(in case of scss) helpers`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#css-and-sass). Rails will automatically make correct paths for you in production and you can set your background as

```
 background-image: image-url("clothes-line.jpg");
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I have images in app/assets/images. Otherwise error Sprockets::FileNotFound will be shown. So it did not solved my problem.

Comment: @user1263663 i asked you, if you have placed your image in public folder and you said yes. Did you try `background-image: image-url("clothes-line.jpg");` in your scss?

Comment: No, I wrote that I have precompiled images in /public/assets. Original images I have in app/assets/images.

Comment: ok my bad. If you have your images in app/assets/images then **image-url will work**

Comment: It should, but its not. I have suspicion, that it is some openshift configuration or cache or I dont know.

Comment: I tried image-url, url(image-path), image_url and image_path . I tried all these forms.

Answer (score 3):

Based on this https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/issues/704#issuecomment-54047730, openshift is missing RAILS_ENV variable with value "production" when precompiling assets

To fix the problem:

1. Login openshift ssh account
2. Then run the following command without quotes "echo production > .env/user_vars/RAILS_ENV"
3. Make any change to any application local file, the repush the git

Comment: That solved the issue for me as well. Thank you for pointing out the workaround.

Comment: also solved this for me even though it's a year old.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late on this but I've also faced the issue of image urls not working on `openshift` despite being precompiled.

Of course as said by @Mandeep, you have to add `image-url` as your sass helpers to generate the image url for your production along with the `signature`.

I guess, its a bug on `openshift` that does not detect `scss` files and when the assets are precompiled, I didn't see the image path as `/assets/image_name-13048eff72a1570dc740b7767eeb3181.png` instead it was `/assets/image_name.png`.

I decided not to get it precompiled on openshift instead just precompile on the local and push. For this to work you have to add `disable_asset_compilation`. 
You can do this by `touch .openshift/markers/disable_asset_compilation` and then precompile assets locally `RAILS_ENV-production rake assets:precompile` and just push your assets with the newly added marker. It should all be working without any issues.

Hope that helps.